# How to take folder location as an input from user in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, upload

I want that user should be able to select the folder which he wants to upload by a jsp page.

Comment: Could you please attach what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume you want the user to select a folder while uploading. For chrome, you can try the following,

`<input type="file" name="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple />`